# How to say "serve" in "The server serves the request"?

Tags: verbs, word-requests, computing

In the computers field, a server **serves** a request (ex: web server).

How to express that in Japanese?

English example documentation for a method that serves a request:

```
/**
 * Serve the request.
 */
public Response serve(Request request)
```

I want to translate that documentation to Japanese, so I write `リクエストを____`

Comment: I'm not familiar with technical English, but do you say "serve a request" in this case (instead of, say, "serve a response")?

Comment: @brokenheadphones: Example usage: http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/06/apache-logs-how-long-does-it-take-to-serve-a-request/

Comment: serveは「(リクエスト)を処理して応答を返す」と「(リソース)を配信する」の両方の意味で使われます(だから直訳しにくい)。ただserve a responseはあまり見ない気がします。

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thank you. In your case, if you refer to the whole process the server does its own work with the request, I think it's better to stick with サーブ.

Comment: @naruto ありがとうございます。一応検索してみたのですが "serve a request" の方が2倍くらいあるようですね（どっちも全部IT用例じゃないのであれですが）。

Comment: Strictly, in English one "*services*" the **request**, not "*serves*"  - one "*serves*" the **response**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is a direct equivalent. If you don't mind rephrasing it, you can use:

- 配信する (to distribute)
- 応答する (to respond)
- 処理する (to process)

But in programming contexts, just using サーブする is also a good idea. There is no good kanji word for *server*, after all.

**EDIT:** The reason why *serve* is difficult to translate literally is because one can say both "serve a request" (the object is something coming into the server) and "serve a file" (the object is something going out of the server). 応答 and 処理 are close to the former sense, and 配信 is close to the latter sense. I think サーブする covers both meanings.

Comment: Oh, speaking of Kanji for "server" -> 服務器 (Not Japanese, Chinese, but still Kanji)

Comment: @sazarando 服務 once was a usable word in Japanese too, but nowadays mostly replaced by サービス.